# Launch Chromium with command line switches has no effect

Tags: command-line, chromium, args

I'm running Chromium 85 on macOS 10.15.3.

I'm trying to use some of the various [command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that Chromium makes available and none of them seem to have any effect. For example

```
./Chromium --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

When it launches and I go to the `chrome://flags` page, the setting has not been enabled:

[image]

I've tried this on multiple versions of Chromium  as well as on Windows with the same results. I can't seem to enable any of them.

I did notice on [this page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) that it says

> Note that if you look at chrome://flags to see if the command line
>   option is active, the state might not be accurately reflected. Check
>   chrome://version for the complete command line used in the current
>   instance.

So maybe it is working and there's just no way to verify that? Checking the `chrome://version` page is not really sufficient to tell if a feature was successfully enabled. It's just echoing back what you passed into the command line.

Comment: Does it work on Windows? And try to enable logging  and checkout the log file for more info

Comment: It does not work on windows. I haven't enabled logging. I'll look into that.

Comment: Chromium 85 is scheduled to be released in three months, but I also can't get this working on Chromium 81 for Linux. I do wonder if that particular GPU-related feature has other hard-coded handling that can't be overridden. Maybe try to find a simpler toggle for testing?

Comment: Actually, I haven't had much success getting any of the command line switches listed on the chrome://flags/ page to work.

Comment: Make sure you kill all the existing chrome processes. You can check if any is running using `pgrep -x "Google Chrome"` and kill them using `sudo killall Google\ Chrome`. After that try the command line parameter. The issue is that when you just launch Chrome like that it looks to re-use existing running instances and the flags they had are only valid

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yeah, I made sure to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noted, `chrome://flags` does not reflect the actual state. It only shows the flags that were enabled via that page. If you supply additional flags the page does not show them enabled, but they can still have an effect.

Try with

```
./Chromium --show-overdraw-feedback
```

and check the flags page. It will not show as enabled, but you can clearly see all the overlays everywhere.

So you can assume your original

```
./Chromium --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

was likely correct and works.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think how that works is pretty silly.

Comment: for example to instantly check if switches are working you can test "--start-maximized" switch