# Launch Chrome with command line switches has no effect

Tags: google-chrome

I type these code below on windows cmd.

with  switch --version

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Default" --version
```

without switch --version

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

then type chrome://version/ on browser for each.
In this case you will see all of both with switch --version on command line property.

could i have this reason? Thanks.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: This --version switch is just a sample, If you use --proxy-server switch,you will see all browser you launch work fine or all doesn't work.

Comment: Could this be helpful for you? [Launch Chromium with command line switches has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894485/launch-chromium-with-command-line-switches-has-no-effect)